# Avoiding nested promises inside a then function JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I have an asynchronous function 'doApiRequest' that is called inside of a 'then' function...

```
doSomething()
  .then(() => {
    return doApiRequest();
  })
  .then((apiResult) => {
    doSomethingElse(apiResult);
  });
```

The issue being that doApiRequest returns a Promise with the eventual result of that API request. However, do to the nature of the API I'm working with there is a request rate limit involved. I plan on handling that by having each API request add itself to a queue, and then when the queue releases the request after waiting for the rate limit, the API request will finish resolving.
While I could do something like...

```
doSomething()
  .then(() => {
    return waitForRateRefresh();
  })
  .then(() => {
    return doApiRequest();
  })
  .then((apiResult) => {
    doSomethingElse(apiResult);
  });
```

I may end up having many 'doApiRequest' calls, so having to chain a 'waitForRateRefresh' on each seems like a bad method and I'd also have to make it work so it can pass along the data from previous then statements. What I'd like to do is handle this inside of 'doApiRequest' itself.

'doApiRequest' would look something like this

```
doApiRequest(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    waitForRateRefresh().then(() => {
      //http call
      resolve(someValue);
    };
  });
}
```

However I'm trying to find a way to do this that doesn't involve nesting Promises. What other ways would there be to go about this. Another way I've though of doing it is by using Async/Await instead, is there any other way of doing it with just promises? What happens (or is it even possible) to return a Promise with an attached then function from 'doApiRequest' like...

```
return waitForRateRefresh().then(() => new Promise(..../http call));
```

In the original then function where 'doApiRequest' is called - will it receive the value returned by 'waitForRateRefresh', or the result of traversing down the then chain attached to it.

Thanks for any insights

Comment: note : `'doApiRequest' would look something like this` avoid the promise constructor antipattern ... the content of that function is simply `return waitForRateRefresh().then(() => {
      //http call
      return someValue;
    };`

Comment: seeing as you `.then(() => {
    return waitForRateRefresh();
  })` and the same for  `doApiRequest` ... there is no incoming "value"  anyway

Comment: @JaromandaX absolutely, in this case though will 'someValue' make it to the original then statement or will only what waitForRateRefresh resolves as be returned

Comment: This is great help, especially being able to wrap it. I created a JSBin here to test some of the different methods and return values https://jsbin.com/dawesen/edit?js,console

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While async/await is great, if you're using an older version of nodejs that doesn't support it, then you'll either need to transpile `async/await` code, or use plain ol' Promises

Don't know if you've ever seen transpiled `async`/`await` - it's quite "verbose"

What you can do, assuming you actually want to pass the result of `doSomething` to `doApiRequest` is this

```
doSomething()
.then(result => waitForRateRefresh().then(() => result))
.then((doSomethingResult) => doApiRequest(doSomethingResult))
.then((apiResult) => doSomethingElse(apiResult));
```

of course, the above can be simplified to

```
doSomething()
.then(result => waitForRateRefresh().then(() => result))
.then(doApiRequest)
.then(doSomethingElse);
```

---

To clarify a point about promise constructor anti-pattern

```
doApiRequest(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        waitForRateRefresh().then(() => {
            //http call
            resolve(someValue);
        };
   });
}
```

this is simplified to

```
doApiRequest(){
    return waitForRateRefresh().then(() => {
        //http call
        return someValue;
    };
}
```

Of course, if `// http call` is asyncrhonous, then `return someValue` can't be used like that. But that would be the case for your version of the code as well

To accept a value from doSomething in this version of doApiRequest, change the code to

```
doApiRequest(someResult){
    return waitForRateRefresh().then(() => {
        //http call - use someResult here
        return someValue;
    };
}
```

The main code is now

```
doSomething()
.then(doApiRequest)
.then(doSomethingElse);
```

Again, though ... the `//http call` and `return someValue` will not work as desired if `someValue` is gathered asynchronously in whatever `http call` is

---

and one more idea so you don't need to rewrite existing functions

create a "wrapper" around `doApiRequest`

```
const qApiRequest = result => waitForRateRefresh().then(() => doApiRequest(result));
```

now, the code is

```
doSomething()
.then(qApiRequest)
.then(doSomethingElse);
```

---

Of course, with `async`/`await` it's just

```
const doSomethingResult = await doSomething();
await waitForRateRefresh();
const apiResult = doApiRequest(doSomethingResult);
const finalResult = doSomethingElse(apiResult);
```

Of course, these would need to be inside a function tagged `async`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, to clarify the second part of your answer makes it so that the .then(result => waitForRateRefresh().then(() => result)) part isn't necessary correct? and someValue is what will be seen outside of doApiRequest()?

Comment: Sorry, the second part is different, let me add how that would be used

Comment: @KyleR - I've added a third possibility, which I think is probably the best, as it doesn't require rewriting `doApiRequest`

Comment: This is great help, especially being able to wrap it. I created a JSBin here to test some of the different methods and return values https://jsbin.com/dawesen/edit?js,console

Answer (score 2):

I would use `async/await`, it keeps the code very readable and makes it easy to reason what is happening next.

```
await doSomething();
await waitForRateRefresh();
const apiResult  = await doApiRequest();
await doSomethingElse(apiResult);
```